# Multiparty computation on circuits that perform group operations

Tags: elliptic-curves, multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits, circuit

I see that a lot of multiparty computation and garbling protocols are implemented for circuits like AES or SHA256.
For my project, I would like to garble a circuit that performs some group operations on elliptic curves and RSA groups.

Are there any circuit compiler libraries or garbling libraries that support this? Are there any estimates on the size of a circuit that performs one group operation?

Comment: Do you _just_ need group operations (i.e. a MPC scheme only supporting group operations would be fine)?

Comment: @SEJPM My actual plan is to implement IBE from DDH protocol proposed by Dottling and Garg. Their circuit performs a bunch of group exponentiations. If I can estimate the circuit size for one group operation, then I can estimate the overall circuit size.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a twitter thread within the last year or so (that I can't find anymore) where Nigel Smart asked a similar question. Also on a relevant note, I just want to place the reminder that MPC circuits can be arithmetic or binary and the former should easily support just describing ECC operations as you'd in software (especially when choosing the MPC field prime to be the ECC prime).

Comment: This paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03370.pdf was discussed in the twitter thread (which I also can't find, only remember the paper). You need 9.2 billion gates or 366,210.94 MB for an exponentiation (curve multiplication) for secp192k1.